# Adding a second and third textField. Can only add first and last

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I want to add a second and third text field using alert but I can only add first and last. Because of this I'm getting two of the same texts for both first and last. I want all four text labels to be different.

I've tried putting in two firsts and two lasts but that obviously wont work so I don't know what else to try.

```
 alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) in

     let nameField = alert.textFields?.first

     let excerciseField = alert.textFields?.first

     let moodField = alert.textFields?.last

     let descriptionField = alert.textFields?.last

     if nameField?.text != "" && descriptionField?.text != "" {

         noteItem.name = nameField?.text
         noteItem.longText = descriptionField?.text
         noteItem.longText2 = excerciseField?.text
         noteItem.longText3 = moodField?.text
```

I want all of the inputs to be different but the first two are the same and the last two are the same.

Comment: Access `textFields` as `alert.textFields?[0]`, `alert.textFields?[1]`, `alert.textFields?[2]`, `alert.textFields?[3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding array of textfield and thats why initial properties of array `Array.first` and `Array.last` you can use. 
To add more textfield you should do something like this

```
let nameField = alert.textFields[0]
let excerciseField = alert.textFields[1]
let moodField = alert.textFields[2]
let descriptionField = alert.textFields[3]
```